# Drawing cyclic quiver

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

How can I draw the cyclic quiver like in the url below?

https://books.google.com/books?id=rZ_z6GpAROoC&pg=PA361

[image]

I tried and wrote the following but it is far from what I want. Would you please help me? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, mathdots}
\newcommand{\pnt}[1]{\stackrel{#1}{\bullet}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{tikzcd}
  & & & \pnt{1} \ar[rd, bend left, "\alpha_1"] & & \\
  & & \pnt{k} \ar[ur, bend left, "\alpha_k"] & & \pnt{2} \ar[rd, bend left, "\alpha_2"]  &   \\
  & \pnt{k-1} \ar[ur, bend left, "\alpha_{k-1}"] & & & & \pnt{3} \ar[ld, bend left, "\alpha_3"] \\
  & & \ddots \ar[ul, bend left, "\alpha_{k-2}"] & & \iddots \ar[ld, bend left, "\alpha_{i-1}"] & \\
  & & & \pnt{i} \ar[ul, bend left, "\alpha_i"] & &
 \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've got a start, which is good - but I would recommend just the `TikZ` package, mostly because I think it's easier to understand the code and adjust it as necessary. I went that route, so feel free to disregard this if you would like to stick to `tikz-cd`. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% All nodes, node labels, and loops
\foreach \ang\lab\anch in {90/1/north, 45/2/{north east}, 0/3/east, 270/i/south, 180/{n-1}/west, 135/n/{north west}}{
  \draw[fill=black] ($(0,0)+(\ang:3)$) circle (.08);
  \node[anchor=\anch] at ($(0,0)+(\ang:2.8)$) {$\lab$};
  \draw[->,shorten <=7pt, shorten >=7pt] ($(0,0)+(\ang:3)$).. controls +(\ang+40:1.5) and +(\ang-40:1.5) .. ($(0,0)+(\ang:3)$);
}

% Top part of circle, arrows between different nodes and their labels
\foreach \ang\lab in {90/1,45/2,180/{n-1},135/n}{
  \draw[->,shorten <=7pt, shorten >=7pt] ($(0,0)+(\ang:3)$) arc (\ang:\ang-45:3);
  \node at ($(0,0)+(\ang-22.5:3.5)$) {$\alpha_{\lab}$};
}

% Bottom part of circle, arrows between different nodes and their labels
\draw[->,shorten <=7pt] ($(0,0)+(0:3)$) arc (360:325:3);
\draw[->,shorten >=7pt] ($(0,0)+(305:3)$) arc (305:270:3);
\draw[->,shorten <=7pt] ($(0,0)+(270:3)$) arc (270:235:3);
\draw[->,shorten >=7pt] ($(0,0)+(215:3)$) arc (215:180:3);
\node at ($(0,0)+(0-20:3.5)$) {$\alpha_3$};
\node at ($(0,0)+(315-25:3.5)$) {$\alpha_{i-1}$};
\node at ($(0,0)+(270-20:3.5)$) {$\alpha_i$};
\node at ($(0,0)+(225-25:3.5)$) {$\alpha_{n-2}$};

% Ellipsis
\foreach \ang in {310,315,320,220,225,230}{
  \draw[fill=black] ($(0,0)+(\ang:3)$) circle (.02);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've tried to label which part of the code does what in your diagram. You can see I made use of the `\foreach` loop command where possible, but with the bottom part of the circle, especially where the arrows are different lengths, it wasn't as straightforward, so I resorted to plain old trial and error. And here's the result:

[image]

If the radius is too large, you can change `\begin{tikzpicture}` to something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]` or similar. This will not change the label size. Also, I notice that your arrow tips are slightly different than the default arrow tips that I've used. To change them, call the `TikZ` library `arrows.meta` in the header (in the same spot as the `calc` library), and add the option `>={Straight Barb[length=5pt, width=3pt]}` to the whole `tikzpicture` (in the same way as mentioned with `scale`).