# How to draw the following diagram using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, technical-drawing

I am trying to draw the following cyclic birth and death chain using tikz:

[image]

The key elements I require are:

1. Labels inside the circles
2. Arrowheads in middle of arrows
3. Ellipses at bottom of diagram
4. Arrows going in both directions at each node.

I found a very similar one over here: [Drawing cyclic quiver](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297525/drawing-cyclic-quiver) , but it lacked arrows going both directions and labels within nodes.

I have drawn this related diagram already:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and explanation of code would also be really helpful!)

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you know that you want to do it with TikZ then you should definitely read an introduction to coding with it, because labels inside circular nodes (`\node[circle, draw]`) are among the basic knowledge you will need. Please help us help you by giving it a try and then posting a minimal code example with which you do need help with.

Comment: Judging by what you have done, you seem to know how to place text in circles, and that the biggest thing missing is to place the nodes in a circular pattern, rather than in a horizontal line. TikZ has the option of using polar coordinates, `(<angle>:<radius>)`, so for example `\node [circle,draw] (m1) at (30:2cm) {$[1]_{m}$};` to place a node at the angle 30 degrees, 2cm from the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it, but since you gave no MWE (not even of the diagram you already made) I don't know if it is of use to you.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{state/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1.75cm}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state] (0)   at ( 90:4) {\( [0]_m \)};
        \node[state] (1)   at ( 45:4) {\( [1]_m \)};
        \node[state] (2)   at (  0:4) {\( [2]_m \)};
        \node[state] (i)   at (270:4) {\( [i]_m \)};
        \node[state] (m-2) at (180:4) {\( [m-2]_m \)};
        \node[state] (m-1) at (135:4) {\( [m-1]_m \)};

        \node[state,draw=none,rotate=315+90] (i-1) at (315:4) {\( \cdots \)};
        \node[state,draw=none,rotate=225+90] (i+1) at (225:4) {\( \cdots \)};

        \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{latex}}},every node/.style={auto,font=\small}]
            \foreach \startnode/\endnode in {0/1,1/2,2/i-1,i-1/i,i/i+1,i+1/m-2,m-2/m-1,m-1/0}{
                \draw[postaction={decorate}] (\startnode) to[bend left=25] node[auto] {\( P_{\startnode} \)} (\endnode);
                \draw[postaction={decorate}] (\endnode)   to[bend left=25] node[auto] {\( 1-P_{\endnode} \)} (\startnode);
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Note that Tikz also has the `automata` library which may be better suited for this type of diagrams. See page 513 of [the PGF manual (v3.0.1a)](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).