# Drawing a circular graph using xypic

Tags: draw, xy-pic, xymtex

How can I draw a circular graph, as in the picture below, using `xypic`?

[image]

Comment: Why has this question been closed? True, the OP should have posted some code, but the request is for a solution with `xypic`, while the proposed solution is TikZ.

Comment: @gernot I am the author of the first closure of the question. Now I reopen it.

Comment: @Snoopy Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you post what you have tried so far, for us to start from? Or is `xypic` not really a requirement and the `tikz` solution is fine?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! Can you please post the link to the `tikz` solution as a comment?

Comment: @gernot Surely....here there is the link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297525/drawing-cyclic-quiver. I not put the code because it is too long by 844 characters.

Comment: @gernot There is also another question with the same picture (I think) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527136/circular-diagram-in-latex

Answer (score 1):

My it is only a comment instead of a true answer, because I think that with `\xymatrix` the way is very very long and with lot of difficulties.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
G& {\overset{\displaystyle 1}{\bullet}}\ar@/^1pc/[dr]^{\alpha_1} &  \\
A& B& {\bullet}\ar@/^1pc/[dl]\\
D& E& F}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My problems are:

1. `@{.}` give me only dotted straight line and not curved arrows withouts tips. In addendum in the picture there are only 3 dots.
2. To put the rotated circle labels. For `1` it is very simple but for the others (????).
3. Create a fast circle loop (see the § 8.2 Circles and Ellipses of the complete/old documentation http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf).

[image]

I should read and to understood the manual and the commands that they are differents from the canonical but not very simple use of the arrows.